# How to burn current DVD Disc in drive to another empty disk

Tags: dvd

I want some figuring help from you guys,I hope you will help me at 100%. I want a software that will burning  current DVD Disc in drive  to another empty disk only.
If there is ,please send me download link.
Thank you and Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

[DVDShrink](http://dvd-shrink.en.softonic.com/) is one of the best free dvd cloning softwares, you can give it a try.

if you only need the software for a short period of time you can always use  Slysoft [AnyDVD](http://www.slysoft.com/en/anydvd.html) 21 days trial version